# How to loop through this array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to figure out how to loop through this array so when i click on the button the next set of answers appear on the screen i feel like I am close but missing something.

```
const questions = [
  {
    question: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
    answers: [
      { Text: 'strings', correct: false },
      { Text: 'booleans', correct: false },
      { Text: 'alerts', correct: true },
      { Text: 'numbers', correct: false },
    ]

  },
  {
    question: 'The condition in an if else statement is enclosed within:___',
    answers: [
      { Text: 'parentheses', correct: true },
      { Text: 'curly brackets', correct: false },
      { Text: 'numbers and strings', correct: false },
      { Text: 'square brackets', correct: false },
    ]
  }
let nextQuestionIndex = 0;
let QI = 0

function displayQuestions() {
  resetState();
  let nextQuestions = questions[nextQuestionIndex]
  let questionNumb = nextQuestionindex + 1;
  question.innerHTML = questionNumb + ". " + nextQuestions.question;
  

  nextQuestions.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = answer.Text;
    button.classList.add("btn");

    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < answer.Text.length; i++) {
       const userChoice = answer.Text[QI[i]];
        button.innerHTML = userChoice;
```

Ive tried to for loop through it but cant figure out the correct way to do it.

Comment: You're going to have to explain exactly what it is that's going wrong. What do you expect to happen? Why? What is confusing you about the results? Are errors reported? etc etc

Comment: There is some code missing  because you didn't close curly braces

Comment: You create a button, but you never add it to the dom

Comment: Sorry, i get the first set of answers to appear and after i click on the button it changes to undefined. Im trying to get it to loop through and display the next set of answers after one has been clicked

Comment: Please add html as well, and fix syntax errors in your code. Use `<>` button to make your code runnable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some code missing and the variable names are a quite misleading so i tried changing some names just to make it more readable. Also global variables aren't my favorite but for this example it isn't that bad.

This is a poorly written example but i hope it illustrates the idea.

```js
const questions = [
  {
    question: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
    answers: [
      { Text: 'strings', correct: false },
      { Text: 'booleans', correct: false },
      { Text: 'alerts', correct: true },
      { Text: 'numbers', correct: false },
    ]

  },
  {
    question: 'The condition in an if else statement is enclosed within:___',
    answers: [
      { Text: 'parentheses', correct: true },
      { Text: 'curly brackets', correct: false },
      { Text: 'numbers and strings', correct: false },
      { Text: 'square brackets', correct: false },
    ]
  }
]

let currentQuestion = 0;
let questionDiv = document.getElementById('question');

function displayQuestions(){
    //Get the next index and validate if it is in a valid index,
    //if not, get back to the first position
    if (currentQuestion < (questions.length-1)) currentQuestion++;
    else currentQuestion = 0;
    
    //Set the text content of the html element called questionDiv
    questionDiv.innerHTML = currentQuestion + ". " + questions[currentQuestion].question;
    
    //Get the current cuestion and loop through the answers
    questions[currentQuestion].answers.forEach((answer, index) => {
        button = document.getElementById(index+1);
        button.innerHTML = answer.Text;
        
        //Add an event listener or the "onclick" attribute for the button to do something
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="question"></div>
<button id="1"></button>
<button id="2"></button>
<button id="3"></button>
<button id="4"></button>
<button id="next" onclick="displayQuestions()">Next</button>
```